# RSQLite Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : namespace ‘DBI’ 0.4-1 is being loaded, but >= 0.8 is required

Tags: r, sqldf, r-dbi, rsqlite

When I load sqldf package, I got error message below. How can I fix this?

```
install.packages("sqldf", dep = TRUE)
library(sqldf)
```

RSQLite
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘DBI’ 0.4-1 is being loaded, but >= 0.8 is required
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘sqldf’ was built under R version 3.3.3
2: package ‘RSQLite’ was built under R version 3.3.3
Error: package ‘RSQLite’ could not be loaded

After this message I try the load RSQLite package

```
install.packages(pkgs = "RSQLite", 
             dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

I got this error message
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'DBI'.

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed by running the code

```
update.packages()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in some packages in R, you need manual installations. Donwload the package from R repository from website then run the code

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL)
```

pick your downloaded zip file from your local.